# bash next month error

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

Running into errors. I am trying to get the next month when a user sends a date in.

```
D="2019/12/01";
D=$(date -d "$D");
echo "Current Date = $D";
```

prints `Current Date = Sun Dec  1 00:00:00 EST 2019`

```
current_month=$(date -d "$D" '+%m');
echo "Current Month = $current_month";
```

prints `Current Month = 12`

```
nextm=$(date -d "$D" "+next months");
echo "Next Month = $nextm";
```

prints `Next Month = next months`
How do I get the next month?

**************** update ************************

```
D="2019/11/01";
D=$(date -d "$D");
echo "Current Date = $D";
Current Date = Fri Nov  1 00:00:00 EDT 2019
current_month=$(date -d "$D" '+%m');
echo "Current Month = $current_month";
Current Month = 11

next_date=$(date -d "$D next month")
echo "Next Date = $next_date";
Next Date = Sat Nov 30 23:00:00 EST 2019
next_year=$(date -d "$next_date" '+%Y');
echo "Next Year = $next_year";
Next Year = 2019
```

printing out november 30 instead of december 1

Comment: Seems to be an issue with daylight savings.  I think you may only be able to avoid this by using UTC or forcing the same UTC offset like `TZ='UTC-4:00' date -d "$D next month"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add one month to your input date string (using GNU date) like so:

```
nextm=$(date -d "$D +1 month")
```

Or:

```
nextm=$(date -d "$D next month")
```

When you quote `$D` and `+next months` separately that becomes two different parameters which will not be read by date in the way you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks.  Is what I have the best way to get the next month. When I changed the date to `2019/11/01` then the next month is `Sat Nov 30 23:00:00 EST 2019` which is incorrect.

Comment: @user3525290: I cannot reproduce that issue, what version of date are you using and what is the exact command that produces that?

Comment: date (GNU coreutils) 8.25.  I will edit my original post to exactly what I have.